# How lightning arrestors are usefull?

Tags: voltage

What is a lightning arrestor? How they work? And where we have to use this in our electrical power system? I think i have saw this at the output of transformer. And also i have notice that, even though we use lightning arrestor, but lightning occur to the transformer. Why this happen?

Comment: Ok.. But i have noticed many times that, even though we use lightning arrestor to transformer. But lightning occur... Why it happenes? Whats the fault?

Answer (score 1):

A lightning arrester is a device (can be just spark gap) that diverts the current of a lightning strike away (mostly to ground), instead of to the circuits downstreams. They work by offering a path to hearth that gets activated by a high voltage.

A lightning arrester is placed between the place where a lightning can strike and the circuits that are to be protected.